# How to store a stored procedure in a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have created a stored procedure for First Name, Last Name & Email Id. Can anyone help me how to store that into a table? Please find the code below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Email_List 
    (@a varchar (20),
     @b varchar (20))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @First_Name varchar (20),
            @Last_Name varchar (20),
            @Email_Id varchar (20)

    SET @First_Name = CAST(@a AS varchar)
    SET @Last_Name = CAST(@b AS varchar)
    SET @Email_Id = LOWER(CAST(@a + '.' + LEFT(@b, 3) + '@abc.com' AS varchar))

    PRINT 'First_Name: ' + @First_Name
    PRINT 'Last_Name: ' + @Last_Name
    PRINT 'Email_Id: ' + @Email_Id
END

DECLARE @a1 varchar (20),
        @b1 varchar(20)

SET @a1 = 'Zee'
SET @b1 = 'Beeee'

EXEC Email_List @a1, @b1
```

Results:

```
First_Name: Zee
Last_Name: Beeee
Email_Id: zee.bee@abc.com
```

How to save the stored procedure in this table?

```
CREATE TABLE Email_contact
(
    First_Name varchar(20),
    Last_Name varchar(20),
    Email_Id varchar(20)
)
```

How to save the stored procedure also in this table?

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpEmail_contact
(
    First_Name varchar(20),
    Last_Name varchar(20),
    Email_Id varchar(20)
)
```

Comment: Stored procedures **aren't** stored in tables - they're just created in the database and stored there.

Comment: Stored procedure are not stored in a table

Comment: I assume you mean "store the output of the stored procedure in a table"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [INSERT...EXEC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql):

```
INSERT INTO Email_contact
    EXEC Email_List @a1,@b1;

INSERT INTO #tmpEmail_contact
    EXEC Email_List @a1,@b1;
```

This requires returning the results as a SELECT query in the proc code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Email_List 
    (@a varchar (20),
     @b varchar (20))
AS

DECLARE @First_Name varchar (20),
        @Last_Name varchar (20),
        @Email_Id varchar (20)

SET @First_Name = CAST(@a AS varchar)
SET @Last_Name = CAST(@b AS varchar)
SET @Email_Id = LOWER(CAST(@a + '.' + LEFT(@b, 3) + '@abc.com' AS varchar))

SELECT
      @First_Name AS First_Name
    , @Last_Name AS Last_Name 
    , @Email_Id AS Email_Id;
GO
```